# Strategy for starting up an EDI system

Tags: biztalk, edi, x12, b2b

I am tasked with creating a system to receive X12 810 version 4010 invoices. I am currently creating a document that will resemble something like a mixture of these:

[Bisg 810 guide](https://www.bisg.org/docs/x12_4010_810.pdf)

[Random House Guide](http://www.randomhouse.biz/vendors/pdf_files/IG_810.pdf)

I intend to send this to the customer telling them this is what our EDI system will accept. Then I will create the EDI system (it is not made yet). I would like to know if I should consider doing something first before this? This is my first time ever with EDI and I would like to know if I am on the right track.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you defined your communication protocol? How to trade? Who to trade with? AS2? VAN?  Why not ask your partner what they can send.  They are probably sending 810s to other customers. Get a sample from them and go from there.

Comment: we have one trading partner we setting things up with. its over as2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are able to dictate the format of the edi you receive, that's great and it makes your life much more simple.

1. As mentioned in a comment below, outline how the data needs to get to you ... e.g. via VAN (sterling, gxs, etc).
2. Create your own document like the ones you mentioned above. Tell the what segments elements are mandatory and under what conditions the optional ones must be sent. Give allowed values for everything.
3. Include samples ... this is often very very helpful to the people trying to adhere to your spec.
4. *if* the sender can already generate edi, then you could also just get a file from them and use it as a baseline. add anything you need that they didn't include and remove the stuff you don't want or can't ignore.